# Action intent broadcast not recieved by application

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have been trying to receive `broadcast` message send by `system` e.g `ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON`. I have been trying to receive the same in our application.

Following is my code

**Android Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>            
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    Toast.makeText(context,"Got Intent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Tag",uri.getHost());
   }
}
```

I ran the application in `debug` mode. When i click the camera button of my device, there is no `OnReceive` event fired in my app.

What i am missing ?

Do i need to register the `broadcast` in my `main.activity` also ?

Comment: what sdk are you pointing to ?

Comment: Android level 23

Comment: did u add permissions ?

Comment: Are u trying to set Broadcastreceiver on camera open or when the physical camera button is pressed?

Comment: On camera open by any means !!

Comment: One more thing, what did u mean by *when I click the camera buton* ? Is it taking a picture ? If yes your intent filter might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: Not working.. I ran the app, press home button so app goes in background. Now hit camera button of device. But nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

For Camera you need to take runtime permission from user because your Api level 23.